# Passing child ref to a parent through a props method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, scroll, parent-child

I have encountered a scenario where I need to pass the ref of an element in child to the parent. I could not do this using the "forwardRef" approach as I render a list of children in the parent component.

I have passed the ref from the child as a method parameter to one of the parent method which is accessible via props. This works and I was able to access the ref in the parent to achieve what I wanted.

I want to know if this approach would result in any future problem or if it is an anti-pattern. Please let me know if the same can be achieved through any other means.

Below is a sample code demonstrating my implementation.

```
export const Child: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {

  const childRef = useRef<any>(null);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    props.onListItemClick(childRef);
  };

  return (
    <li onClick={clickHandler} ref={childRef}>
      {props.key} - {props.item.name}
    </li>
  );
};
```

```
export const Parent: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {

  const listItemClickHandler = (clickedChildRef: any) => {
    // use the child ref to set the scroll
    if (clickedChildRef && clickedChildRef.current) {
      clickedChildRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
    }
  };

  return (
    <ol>
      {props.data.map((item: any, index: number) =>
        <Child item={item} key={index} onListItemClick={listItemClickHandler} />
      )}
    </ol>
  )
};
```

Comment: You don't need a ref at all. The first argument to `onClick` function is the event which contains the element. Just pass it up

Comment: This is just a minimal sample to explain my scenario. In the real implementation, the code needs to be fired from a callback from a custom component and it doesn't pass the element in it's event data @AdamJenkins

Comment: It doesn't minimally demonstrate your actually problem. What does the custom component pass in it's event data?

Comment: The custom component just passes an dbKey which is a primary key to identify the item, but that cannot be used to get reference of the item. Even if we could, would it be ideal to pass the element directly like you pointed in your first comment? Since react recommends to use refs for manipulating DOM

Comment: If you need the element reference (for the purposes of scrolling to it), and have control over the callback and are able to pass it as an argument, it's the simplest solution (simplest = best). Why create a ref to get access to an element at the time when it's clicked, when you already have a ref (in the click handler)?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if this approach would result in any future problem or
> if it is an anti-pattern. Please let me know if the same can be
> achieved through any other means.

Your approach might work, not sure. But there is official [example](https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#how-to-manage-a-list-of-refs-using-a-ref-callback) for working with list of refs (here I have adapted it for custom components):

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

const MyComponent = React.forwardRef(function MyInput(props, ref) {
  React.useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => {
      return {
        test: () => {
          console.log('someProp', props.someProp);
        },
      };
    },
    []
  );

  return <div>Hello</div>;
});

export default function App() {
  const itemsRef = React.useRef(null);

  function getMap() {
    if (!itemsRef.current) {
      // Initialize the Map on first usage.
      itemsRef.current = new Map();
    }
    return itemsRef.current;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            itemsRef.current.get('3').test();
          }}
        >
          Call the test method for the third item
        </button>
        <ul>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <MyComponent
              key={item.id}
              someProp={item.id}
              ref={(node) => {
                const map = getMap();
                if (node) {
                  map.set(item.id, node);
                } else {
                  map.delete(item.id);
                }
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const items = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  items.push({
    id: i.toString(),
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Giorgi Moniava for pointing me to the article. That's helpful. I will try to implement in a similar fashion since it is suggested by the official docs and see if it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, `useRef` here is superfluous, the two snippets are equivalent in functionality:

```
export const Child: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {

  const childRef = useRef<any>(null);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    props.onListItemClick(childRef);
  };

  return (
    <li onClick={clickHandler} ref={childRef}>
      {props.key} - {props.item.name}
    </li>
  );
};
```

When you could just do this:

```
export const Child: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {

  const clickHandler = (e) => {
    // although you wouldn't need to pass it as an object with key current
    // it's just an example to show that useRef isn't needed
    props.onListItemClick({current:e.target});
  };

  return (
    <li onClick={clickHandler}>
      {props.key} - {props.item.name}
    </li>
  );
};
```